# code does not retrieve if score1 and score2 are both 0

Tags: sql, join, left-join

desired output is to show every match with the goals scored by each team but the result does not include if score1 and score2 are both 0 (zero)

```
SELECT mdate,
  team1,
  sum(CASE WHEN teamid=team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score1,
  team2,
  sum(CASE WHEN teamid=team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score2
FROM game JOIN goal ON matchid = id
GROUP BY mdate,matchid,team1,team2
ORDER BY mdate,matchid,team1,team2
```

tables

[image]

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`

Comment: There is no question in this post. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre][How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)
 Please use standard spelling & punctuation. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no records in the table `goal` with particular matchid. And if there are no matches, `JOIN` returns no rows. You should try `LEFT JOIN`. This will ensure there is at least one returned row for each game.

```sql
SELECT mdate,
  team1,
  sum(CASE WHEN teamid=team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score1,
  team2,
  sum(CASE WHEN teamid=team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score2
FROM game LEFT JOIN goal ON matchid = id
GROUP BY mdate,matchid,team1,team2
ORDER BY mdate,matchid,team1,team2
```

See the [W3schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) for examples on `[INNER] JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` and `FULL JOIN`.

Answer (score 2):

Just to display matches with at least one goal:

```sql
SELECT mdate,
  team1,
  team2,
FROM game gm
where exists (select 1 from gl go where gl.matchid = gm.id)
```

To show matches with number of goals by teams:

```sql
with
    all_goals as (
        select
            matchid,
            teamid,
            count(*) total_goals
    )
select
    mdate,
    team1,
    team2,
    coalesce(t1.total_goals, 0),
    coalesce(t2.total_goals, 0)
from
    game gm
    left join all_goals t1 on (
        t1.matchid = gm.id
        and t1.teamid = gm.team1
    )
    left join all_goals t2 on (
        t1.matchid = gm.id
        and t2.teamid = gm.team2
    )
where
    t1.total_goals is not null
    or t2.total_goals is not null
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because while there are no goals scored in a match that means you don't have a record in `goal` table. So `FROM game JOIN goal ON matchid = id` don't match. Use `FROM game LEFT JOIN goal ON matchid = id` to get all game records whether goal exists or not.